# make SUM or total for iif statement

Tags: ms-access

I have an expression in textbox for report:

```
=IIf([txtperformance]<20000,Int(0),IIf([txtperformance] Between 20001 And 27999,Int(12),IIf([txtperformance]>28000,Int(25))))
```

Is there any way to make SUM all of the text box result or total calculation?

Comment: `=textbox1 + textbox2 + … textbox10`. SUM is an aggregate function to total a single field and must refer to field, not controls on form.

Comment: sorry i did't arrange my words very well.... actually i make it on report then sort it by week, so there's text box [txt_box] is only one but the report make it many...so how can i make total of it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expression can be simpler. I don't see need for Int() and there is 1 too many IIf and no need for BETWEEN AND.

Put a textbox in group and/or report header or footer for the Sum() calculation.

Aggregate function must reference field that is in report RecordSource or an expression that uses a field. Options are:

1. If you can do that IIf() calculation in a query, and that query is the RecordSource of report, then can reference that constructed field in Sum() function.
2. If txtperformance is a field, not a textbox, then the Sum() function can be applied to that entire IIf() expression.

`=Sum(IIf([txtperformance] < 20000, 0, IIf([txtperformance] < 28000, 12, 25)))`